# Run a docker container inside a Go server

Tags: bash, docker, go

I am trying to run a docker container in a Go server with using `exec.Command`.

Here is my code to run:

```golang
entrypoint := "/bin/bash"
run := fmt.Sprintf("docker run -a stdout -a stderr --rm %s %s %s", env, image, args)
cmd := exec.Command(entrypoint, "-c", run)
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

where env is something like:

```
-e KEY=VALUE
```

However, I get an error such as:

```
/bin/bash: docker run ... : No such file or directory
```

Then, I added double-quotes to the beginning and the end of docker command:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(entrypoint, "-c", "\""+run+"\"")
```

This time, I can run command `/bin/bash -c "docker run ..."` in my Zsh terminal. However Go still throws the same error.

What should I do?

Comment: You should probably use the [Docker Go SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/#go-sdk) rather than try to use the `docker` command-line tool.  Be aware that launching a container at all requires significantly elevated privileges and comes with responsibilities to clean up after yourself, and a Docker-specific approach may not work in other container environments like Kubernetes.

Comment: @DavidMaze so you say it wont work when I deploy my server to Kubernetes?

Comment: Does the docker command exist in the path where the Go binary is running?

Comment: Correct, in Kubernetes you are highly likely to not have direct access to the Docker daemon (if it's running at all) and there's a separate Kubernetes API.

Comment: @DavidMaze so is it ok to use docker go client with Kubernetes? Or, it is still a bad idea?

Comment: It won't work, and running unmanaged containers outside the kubelet framework is also a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the docker run command and all its arguments as a single argument. Instead, try this:

```
cmd := exec.Command(entrypoint, "-c", "docker", "run", "-a", "stdout", "-a", "stderr", "--rm", <break up env>, image, args)
```

Comment: it still throws error about wrong usage of docker run and give instructions: Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND ...

Comment: You have to break up env as well